# youtube's api for app use

Tags: objective-c, youtube-api

Can anyone guide me on how to get youtube's API's to play songs inside the app ?
I need to implement a view with `UISearchBar` where the user searches for any video on youtube (channel etc .. ) and the results are filtered in a `UITableView` with the thumbnail, title, and description.

The user gets to choose a video and this video gets opened in another view.

I just need the search because i've been searching for a week and i can't find any result.

PLEASE help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube api has a good tutorial page for their iOS helper library that you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper).

In order to retrieve youtube videos using a search string, you'll need to use the youtube api.

You might have to make a get request to

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search
```

The required parameters include

> part -The part parameter specifies a comma-separated list of one or
>   more search resource properties that the API response will include.
>   Set the parameter value to snippet.

You may want to add the search string parameter as well (q), if you are searching for a particular string .

For example a query looks like:

```
 GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q=hello&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

and you get the JSON response containing the youtube ids for the videos matching the search string provided.You can see the details [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

This youtube id can then be used to play the video in a Web View according to the iOS helper library.

```
[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"M7lc1UVf-VE"];
```